# what intents im i missing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I’m getting an error about missing intents but I can't find what intents I am missing. I tried some different things but none of them worked.
What am I missing here? The code below is only a part of my full code

```
 throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
            ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Discord.js\application\application.js:6:24)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Discord.js\index.js:89:37)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:23:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:345:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'apps',
    description: 'Apply for staff team',
    async execute(message, args, Discord) {

        const { Client, Intents, Message, Collection} = require('discord.js');



        const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES], partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL'] });
        client.commands = new Collection();

        const setup = require('../setup');
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(setup.GuildID())
        let channelID = setup.AppChannel();


        message.channel.send(`${message.author}, check your dm!`);
        console.log(`New application has started by --> ${message.author.tag}`);

        try {

            setTimeout(embed, 8000)
            console.log(`sending information embed to ${message.author.tag}`)
            function embed() {
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                    .setTitle('APPLICATION')
                    .setFooter('Made by Navid_16#6966')
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'First Name', value: 'Your name' },
                        { name: 'Last Name', value: 'surname' },
                        { name: 'How old are you', value: 'Your age' },
                        { name: 'Your email', value: 'example@example.com' },
                        { name: 'What is your time zone', value: 'GMT+2' },
                        { name: 'Where are you from', value: 'Your country' },
                        { name: 'What languages are you speaking', value: 'englinsh' },
                        { name: 'Have your ever been punished on our server', value: 'did you ever get ban,mute,etc' },
                        { name: 'On which server your most active on', value: 'what mode do you play most' },
                        { name: 'Have you ever been in a staff team', value: 'do you have any experience' },
                        { name: 'Tell us about your self', value: 'tell us something you would like to know about you' }
                    )

                message.author.send({ embeds: [embed] })
            }

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `await` before require from `discord.js`

Comment: `require` doesn’t return a promise. That is not the problem

Comment: @TomaszStaszkiewicz i try await require('discord.js'); but it still the same

Comment: Why are you creating a new client inside your command? Just use `message.client`. You should be using 1 client throughout the entire environment

Comment: okay, so i remove that but still the same

Comment: i wanna apologize it was my mistake i was editing the wrong file all that time

Comment: Is there a reason why you initialize `client` in your message event instead in your main file?

Comment: @Variable i have the client in my main file but i was getting some problems like client was undefiend, so i add it there and when i fix that problem i didn't remove it

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create one client in your main files such as index.js or main.js, creating a client in each command just doesn't make sense, it is like making 1 bot for each command, so only put the client once in your index.js, if you have it somewhere else remove it and if you need it export it from your index, if you need more help you can comment on this and I'll help you.

Comment: yea, i did that. Now i have my client only on my index.js! thanks